# First Get and then Post google sheet data to firebase database using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-httpclient

I am trying to get the data from google sheet in the `JSON` form and then post those data to firebase database using angular.
So Far I am able to get the google sheet data in the form of JSON: [image]
the response I am getting is array of columns and rows. My question is How can I make post request to firebase to post these response ?
To make the get request I did following method.
landing-page.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { Field } from '../model/field';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.page.scss'],
})

export class LandingPagePage implements OnInit {
  private collection: AngularFirestoreCollection;
  myCollection: Observable<Field[]>;
   constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router:Router, private http :HttpClient,private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.collection = this.afs.collection("Exceldata");
    this.myCollection = this.collection.valueChanges(); 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.excelData();
    
  }
logout()
{
  this.auth.signOut();
}
excelData(){

   var sf = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qeCEUlVt_hnuyhnoT1wxMMSv7kZW1s4cUIRLynJ0TxQ/gviz/tq";
 this.http.get(sf,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res=>{
   const data =res.toString().match(/google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(([\s\S\w]+)\)/);
   if(data && data.length==2){
     const obj=JSON.parse(data[1]);
     const table=obj.table;
     const header =  table.cols.map(({label}) => label);
     const rows = table.rows.map(({c}) => c.map(({v}) => v));
     console.log(header);
     console.log(rows); 
     console.log(this.collection.doc().set(Object.assign({}, rows)));
    }
       
 });
}
}
```

Field.ts

```
export interface Field{
    Id:string;
    Name:string;
    Major:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install AngularFirestore
2. Declarations:

private collection: AngularFirestoreCollection;

myCollection: Observable<Model[]>;

3.

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
            this.collection = this.afs.collection<Model>("collectionName");
            this.myCollection = this.collection.valueChanges();
          }
```

4. In your function:

   this.collection.doc().set(Object.assign({}, newItemToSave));

Comment: what will be the `Model[]` ?Do I need to make interface class for it ?

Comment: I am getting following error
 `Type 'Observable<DocumentData[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Model[]>'.
  Type 'DocumentData[]' is not assignable to type 'Model[]'.
  Type 'DocumentData' is missing the following properties from type 'Model': Id, Name, Major`

Comment: Yes the model should be your database schema eg { id, name, major }

Comment: I tried by adding Model but I am getting above error:
`export interface Model{
    Id:string;
    Name:string;
    Major:string;
}`
I have update my code after the change.

Comment: private collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Model>;

Comment: One more question: It post every time whenever I refresh page how do I stop posting repetitively ? I just want to post new  data only not the old one.?

Comment: Move step 4 into its own function that you can call maybe on button click/any other condition. Shouldn't be in the constructor if that's where you put it.